# Create a widget in an UnconstrainedBox and then size it to the screen without getting RenderOverflow errors

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create a widget that looks like a German car sign. To do so, I read the specification

Since this is an official sign, there is plenty of specification available about sizes. I simply map the official size in millimeters to pixels for a first start. For example, the official width of the sign is 520 mm, so I'm using 520 px.

My idea is to start with an `UnconstrainedBox` that has a `Container` of the official width/height.

```dart
UnconstrainedBox(
  child: Container(
  width: _width,
  height: _height,
));
```

I was expecting that I get an RenderOverflow error, because the widget will be wider than the iPhone 15 view port:

[image: RenderOverflow Error]

So, I thought I can use a Transform.scale and scale everything down so it fits back into the device, like this:

```
Transform.scale(
  scale: 0.5,
  child: GermanCarSign(),
);
```

[image: Scaled RenderOverflow error]

However, I still see the RenderOverflow error. Visually, the widget would fit into the viewport now.

So, what would be the correct approach to create a widget that follows a certain specification and then scale the whole thing so it fits into the viewport without getting a RenderOverflow error?

I've tried fiddling around with `AspectRatio` or `OverflowBox` widget, but I did not have success, maybe I did it wrong.

Comment: how did you use `OverflowBox`? try to find in flutter sources how it is used in several places (I believe `InteractiveViewer` uses it)

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/ead455963c/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/interactive_viewer.dart#L1276

Comment: @pskink do you want to post your comment as an answer, so I can accept it? It was indeed a misusage of the Overflow box. With your example I could get it to work. :)

Comment: good to hear, feel free to write a self answer then... - i am basically too lazy ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink) pointed me to a [repo](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/ead455963c/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/interactive_viewer.dart#L1276) for the correct usage of the `OverflowBox` widget.

In my case, I did the following to get the result I desire:

```dart
@override
Widget build(final BuildContext context) =>
    LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (final context, final constraints) =>
          Transform.scale(
            scale: constraints.maxWidth / _width, // _width = 520
            child: OverflowBox(
              minWidth: constraints.minWidth,
              minHeight: constraints.minHeight,
              maxWidth: double.infinity,
              maxHeight: double.infinity,
              child: SizedBox(
                width: _width,
                height: _height,
                child: const Placeholder(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
    );
```

Comment: btw do you really need `UnconstrainedBox` with `SizedBox` child? it looks strange at first sight, also if you have `SizedBox` at the end maybe `SizedOverflowBox` could be used?

Comment: @pskink The `UnconstrainedBox` is indeed not necessary. However, combinding the SizedBox with the OverflowBox into a `SizedOverflowBox` did not work for me. Than the widget has a complete different size.

Comment: good to know, I did not check that `SizedOverflowBox` ...